# F# MSIL obfuscation

Tags: f#, obfuscation, disassembly

Two obfuscation-related questions:

1) Is there any tool that can disassemble F# back to its source form, or something close to it, from the MSIL target form? This is not an attempt at security through obscurity but I want to protect some source code from "theft".

2) I looked briefly at some F# compiler output and in general it appears pretty gibberish compared to what you get if you disassemble C# compiled code, presumably because C# is closer to the MSIL intermediate representation. The only partly mangled code I've seen from the C# compiler is iterators (and presumably async as of C# 5.0).

So far my impression is that the F# compiled code is reasonably "obfuscated" but is that true? (I realize this is a somewhat subjective question.)

Comment: How good are your adversaries? Any competent malware analyst can reverse your code from a memory dump, never mind IL. From whom are you "protecting" your source?

Comment: Potential competitor. I find it unlikely but better safe than sorry. I just don't want the code to be easily de-obfuscatable with the right tools. It should be hard enough that it's easier to write the code yourself. I don't think malware analysts are in the target range. More like someone with an intermediate-level understanding of F#. :-)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's obfuscated. It's just translated.  All the F# sugaring is undone. Also if you decompile it it's pretty obvious that it came from F#, and any semi-experienced F#/C# personal can re-synthesize the F# from the decompiled version. There are patterns that occur, and all you'd have to do is create a few test scenarios to see what the decompiler does and you can see how things are worked out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. I haven't heard of anything like this; however, I think it's quite likely such a tool will appear in the relatively-near future.
2. Assemblies produced by the F# compiler (i.e., MSIL and related metadata) aren't obfuscated in any way. However, some of the code it produces is far different than the code produced by the C# or VB.NET compilers, so it's not going to be as easy to reverse-engineer (simply because the tools to do so aren't available). Of course, as @Craig Stuntz said, this doesn't afford much protection against an experienced, motivated attacker.

If you're really paranoid, you might consider using an obfuscation tool on your compiled assemblies before shipping them. I've been using [{SmartAssembly}](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/) with F# since late 2010, so I know that one works with F#; if you go with another tool, make sure you test it against some reasonably complicated F# assemblies before buying it -- at the time I was looking for an obfuscator, many of them didn't work correctly (or at all) with F# assemblies.

I wrote up some notes a while back about obfuscating F# assemblies, if you want to read more: [Any experience using .NET obfuscators on F# assemblies?](http://fpish.net/topic/None/74105#comment-74121)

Answer (score 1):

F# is part of the .NET language therefore it can be decompiled. You can have a look at RedGate's Reflector if you want to spend money or 0xd4d's dnSpy (and yes, its the same developer as the very-well known deobfuscator De4Dot). Decompiled code is really close to hard-coded code, the logic is still the same and you can copy/paste the source code.

If you want to protect a F# application you may consider using an obfuscator, & currently they are almost all handled by De4Dot so it's hard to choose wisely, though [.NETGuard](http://netguard.io/) is really strong, it can handle F# applications, it can produce a native output & it has some strong constant protection and De4Dot cannot handle it.